# a way to use Paramiko ssh / scp functionality from Unix to Windows or Windows to Windows?

Tags: python, networking, ssh, scp, paramiko

is there a way to use Python paramiko package in order to scp or ssh from Unix to Windows or from Windows to Windows ?

It works very well from Windows to Unix and from Unix to Unix but not for the other configurations.

#### My code is

```
client = SSHClient()   
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())    
client.connect ('192.168.0.10', 22, 'username', 'pwd')  
transport = client.get_transport ()  
channel = transport.open_session ()  
channel.set_combine_stderr (True)  
channel.exec_command ("dir C:/")
```

#### I get the following error message

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "paramiko_test_scp.py", line 50, in 
        client.connect ('192.168.0.10', 22, 'username', 'pwd')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 291, in connect
        sock.connect(addr)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
        return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
    socket.error: [Errno 10061]

Comment: I would guess the problem is, that on windows (by default) there is no SSH daemon which can take SSH connections. You need to run it there manually before you can use ssh/scp.

Comment: @ZeissS Do you mean I need to install a SSH server tool on the PC I want to access... a tools like cygwin ?

Comment: Yes, you need a ssh server. Un*x/Linux contains one by default, but windows doesn't. I don't know whether cygwin contains a SSH Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows socket error 10061 means : no connection, target machine actively refused it.
- Is your SSH server running (are you using OpenSSH ?)
- Try to disable your firewall

Comment: I have not installed any software. I only have the initial OS configuration. You mean that using ssh or scp with paramiko require the installing of a SSH server like OpenSSH ?... quite annoying

Comment: Yes, Windows does not embedd an ssh server, try this tutorial [How to install OpenSSH sshd server and sftp server on a Windows Server](http://chinese-watercolor.com/LRP/printsrv/cygwin-sshd.html)

Comment: If you dont want/can install ssh at windows servers, try using [winRM](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm)